# Rewriting or breaking function linkage for C unit testing at compile time

Tags: c, unit-testing, linker, function-pointers

For unit testing in C, what I'd like to do is build two object files (A and B) in the production souces which call functions in each other. Then for unit testing provide mock/fake implementations of A and B which could be switched in and out at runtime for unit testing.

What I want to be able to do is link together A, B, fake_A and fake_B into one big test binary which can switch between the production and fake implementation of a module at runtime to unit test both.
This is because it would be nice to avoid building multiple different test binaries for every case and having to consolidate the results.

I will be compiling A and B specifically for unit test so can force extra headers, defines, compiler flags etc. that won't be present at runtime.

I'm wondering if it's possible to break the linkage between functions in A and B by some kind of rewriting or link-time tricks.

Let me try to illustrate. Let's say I have files a.c, b.c, fake_a.c and fake_b.c:

a.c

```
void a_work(void) {
  b_work();
}
```

b.c

```
void b_work(void) {
  do_some_work();
}
```

fake_b.c

```
/* for test, when a_work() calls b_work() I want this to be run */
void b_work(void) {
  if (fake_b_enabled)
    do_fake_b_work();
  else
    // call the real b_work() somehow
}
```

Normally a_work()'s call to b_work() would be linked to the real b_work() at link time, it's that that I want to intercept or rewrite.

I'm thinking about some kind of wrapping with a function pointer layer, but I don't know a way to do it.

Comment: Why not just link against a different object file?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Use shared objects (on *nix, or DLLs on Windows).  Implement your functions in both test and production ways, but build one shared library for each.  Then if you want one binary that switches between them, use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to make the binary load one other than the one you built it with.

Comment: Interesting idea. The point is partly to get one binary that I can call once and execute all tests, though. I wonder if I can use runtime loading and unloading to do that.

Comment: Just run the test multiple times using a script.